# win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application") not working

Tags: python, email, outlook

I am trying to send email using my Outlook client through a Python script. When the below Python script is executed separately from IDLE editor, it is working fine. But when the same lines of codes are put at the end of another Python script (so that after the logic execution email is triggered) and the Python script is called from a Web application hosted in Tomcat server, it is not working.

Code Snippet:

```
#!/Python36/python.exe -u

import win32com.client`

mail_subject = "Test Mail Subject"

mail_body    = "Test Mail Body"

Outlook      = Win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
mail         = Outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To      = 'xxx@abc.com'
mail.Subject = mail_subject
mail.Body    = mail_body
mail.Send()
```

To check where it is failing, I had printed some comments after each line. It was found that the line:
`Outlook = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")`

was failing when the Python script was executed from the Web application. Can anyone help with the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

i ran into this problem and saw this post. No one has answered yet. The python code snippet use `import win32com.client` which use Outlook's COM interface, which is only available when specific user is active (not active means locked or logged off). So it worked normally from IDLE but did not from web server (web server runs with service account i think).

You can interact directly with Outlook using API or something else but avoid using COM interface.

Please refer to the website below for an alternative way：https://medium.com/@manojkumardhakad/python-read-and-send-outlook-mail-using-oauth2-token-and-graph-api-53de606ecfa1

Comment: COM *is* the Outlook API (Outlook Objec tModel or Extended MAPI). And most feature-rich at that. The only non-COM API is command line or `mailto` protocol handler.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question description of the problem, you can use try the following two ways alternatively:

1．Please include the code below before `win32com.Client.Gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")`

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
```

2．You should use the following code replace the code The `win32com. Client.Gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")`

```
Gencache. EnsureDispatch ("Outlook.Application")
```

Please refer to the website below for details：
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/103552/win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch

If you have any question, please reply to me.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried both the options, but both did not solve the issue. The failure was at the line:  gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application"). One difference I could see though is the performance. Previously it was taking 2-3 minutes for the page to refresh before the failure, but when the above suggested codes were used, it took 5 seconds for the page to refresh and show the failure.

Comment: Here is the error log:[Traceback (most recent call last):]
[  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 89, in _GetGoodDispatch]
[    IDispatch = pythoncom.connect(IDispatch)]
[pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable', None, None)]
[]

Comment: Is it possible that the Python version is incorrect ? Seem you are using win32 version of the python and it could cause some unknown issue if you run it on a 64bit envirment. Also does your script run successfully in a different envirment or run standalone ?

Comment: I am running the script in my 64 bit laptop. When the python script is being executed standalone through IDLE, it is running perfectly. But when executed through a web application, I am getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Is it possible that your application is limited to “outlook.Application” when using the outlook. The error log on :“pywintypes.com_error: (-2147221021, 'Operation unavailable'”

Comment: Hi Alina LI-Msft, thanks for replying back. Actually my requirement is :  when a data is loaded to MongoDB through a Webpage xyz.py, post successful load an email should be triggered through the user's outlook to the Site administrator informing that a fresh set of data has been loaded. My data file is getting loaded properly, but when the mail sending lines mentioned at the beginning are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook, just like any other Office app, cannot an should not be used from a service, e.g., IIS or pretty much any Web Server.

Firstly, it can and does display prompts, and, secondly, it is designed to run for a particular local user who has already ran and configured Outlook. Thirdly, even if the user contexts are the same, security contexts are not - running interactively is different from running under a web server: even if the local user is the same, if Outlook is already running, your code will attempt to connect to the already ruining instance (Outlook is a singleton and only one instance of outlook.exe is ever running), COM system will refuse to marshal calls between different security contexts.